# Unable to replace the nan values using the fillna function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, fillna

I have a pandas dataframe. I am trying to replace the nan values of one of the columns with last valid observation using the ffill method of fillna function. But that just dosen't seem to work.

I have verified that the nan values of column are actually nan values and not strings

[This image is a small snapshot of the dataframe. The last column is whose nan values I want to replace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISUzQ.jpg)
[This snapshot is of the console showing that the column nan values are actually nan values and not strings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVEVS.jpg)

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Please help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! For more specific answers, see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). Also at some point, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), it's pretty quick.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
df['1900CE_IV'] = df['1900CE_IV'].fillna(method = 'ffill')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your last column has values which are one-element Lists. Hence ffill will not operate directly. You could convert to a value, use `ffill`  and then convert back to a List (assuming this is what you want) as the simple example below demonstrates:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,2,3],
                   'y': [[7], [8], [np.nan]]
                   })

print(df)

df['y'] = df['y'].map(lambda v: v[0]).ffill().map(lambda v: [v])

print(df)
```

gives:

```
   x      y
0  1    [7]
1  2    [8]
2  3  [nan]

   x      y
0  1  [7.0]
1  2  [8.0]
2  3  [8.0]
```